# Elasticsearch is not returning a document I expect in the search results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a collection of customers that have a first name, last name, email, description and owner id. I want to take a character string from the app, and search on all the fields, with a priority order. Im using boost to achieve that.

Currently I have a lot of test customers with the name Sean in various fields within the documents. I have 2 documents that contain an email with sean.jones@email.com. One document contains the same email in the description.

When I perform the following search, im missing the document in the search results that does not contain the email in the description.

Here is my query:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "match" : {
          "ownerId" : "acct_123"
        }
      },
      "must" : [
        {
          "bool" : {
            "should" : [
              {
                "prefix" : {
                  "firstName" : {
                    "value" : "sean",
                    "boost" : 3
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "prefix" : {
                  "lastName" : {
                    "value" : "sean",
                    "boost" : 3
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "terms" : {
                  "boost" : 2,
                  "description" : [
                    "sean"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "prefix" : {
                  "email" : {
                    "value" : "sean",
                    "boost" : 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the document that Im missing:

```
{
  "_index" : "xxx",
  "_id" : "cus_123",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_type" : "customers",
  "_seq_no" : 9096,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "firstName" : null,
    "id" : "cus_123",
    "lastName" : null,
    "email" : "sean.jones@email.com",
    "ownerId" : "acct_123",
    "description" : null
  }
}
```

When I look at the current results, all of the documents have a score of 3.0. They have "Sean" in the name as well, so they score higher. When I do an _explain on the document im missing, with the query above, I get the following:

```
{
    "_index": "xxx",
    "_type": "customers",
    "_id": "cus_123",
    "matched": true,
    "explanation": {
        "value": 1.0,
        "description": "sum of:",
        "details": [
            {
                "value": 1.0,
                "description": "sum of:",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": 1.0,
                        "description": "ConstantScore(email._index_prefix:sean)",
                        "details": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "value": 0.0,
                "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": 0.0,
                        "description": "# clause",
                        "details": []
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 1.0,
                        "description": "ownerId:acct_123",
                        "details": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here are my mappings:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "text",
      "index_prefixes": {
        "max_chars": 10,
        "min_chars": 1
      }
    },
    "email": {
      "analyzer": "my_email_analyzer",
      "type": "text",
      "index_prefixes": {
        "max_chars": 10,
        "min_chars": 1
      }
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "text",
      "index_prefixes": {
        "max_chars": 10,
        "min_chars": 1
      }
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "ownerId": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

```
        "my_email_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
        }
```

If im understanding this correctly, because this document is only scoring a 1, its not meeting a particular threshold. Ive tried adjusting the min_score but I had no luck. Any thoughts on how I can get this document to be included in the search results?

thanks so much

Comment: Please paster your index creating script here. what types of these fields?

Comment: @YouXiang-Wang all done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what mean by "missing":

1. is it, that the document does not make it into the number of hits (the "total")?
2. or is it, that the document itself does not show up as a hit in the hits list?

If it's #2 you may want to increase the number of documents Elasticsearch fetches and returns, by adding a `size`-clause to your search request (default size is 10):

**Example**

```
"size": 50
```

Comment: this was the issue! you're a life saver! I had no idea there was a limit param like this!